# Determining Automatic Parameters used by Mathematica

Tags: plotting, options, optional-arguments

When you use plotting functions like `ContourPlot3D`, there are lots of parameters that are left as `Automatic` if you do not specify them. I was wondering if there was a way to find out what value was used in these cases.

For example, with my `ContourPlot3D` call, I noticed that there were some missing features. I know I can increase `PlotPoints` to get more finely grained samples, but it would be helpful if I could find out what *Mathematica* used originally (by default) so I can choose a more appropriate value. I know I can use trial and error to get a suitable value, but since `ContourPlot3D` takes a few minutes to evaluate for me, this method is not ideal.

Comment: Unfortunately [`AbsoluteOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) seems to be rather limited. It provides for instance the `PlotRange`, the `ViewPoint` and some other things, but not `PlotPoints`.

Comment: There's no general way to do this, unfortunately.  In some cases it can be rather frustrating.  As it is, this question cannot be answered well.  I suggest you ask about specific options that you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

```
aa = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}]

Options[aa]
```

`{DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   DisplayFunction :> Identity, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
   Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 4 \[Pi]}, {0, 4 \[Pi]}}, 
   PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
   PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], 
   Scaled[0.02]}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic}}`

or...

```
`AbsoluteOptions[aa]`
```

`{AlignmentPoint -> Center, 
  AspectRatio -> 1., 
  Axes -> {False, False}, 
  AxesLabel -> None, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0., 0.}, 
  AxesStyle -> {None, None},
  Background -> None, 
  BaselinePosition -> Automatic, 
  BaseStyle -> {}, 
  ColorOutput -> Automatic, 
  ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
  CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
  DisplayFunction -> Identity, 
  Epilog -> {}, 
  FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> None, 
  FrameStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}, 
                 {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}, 
                 {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}, 
                 {GrayLevel[0.], AbsoluteThickness[0.25]}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{}, {}, {}, {}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> {}, 
  GridLines -> {{}, {}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
  ImageMargins -> 0., 
  ImagePadding -> All, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic, 
  ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, 
  LabelStyle -> {}, 
  Method -> {"DefaultBoundaryStyle" -> Automatic}, 
  PlotLabel -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{0., 12.5664}, {0., 12.5664}}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}, 
  PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
  PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, 
  Prolog -> {}, 
  RotateLabel -> True,
  Ticks -> {{}, {}}, 
  TicksStyle -> {}}`